# how to minimize the massive message delay paho mqtt

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, delay, message, paho

I have seven raspberry pi's as clients a and one raspberry pi as client b which are transferring messages between each other via mqtt. It's working well so far, but there is a massive delay of over 2s sometimes. Most of the times the the delay is arround 0,02-0,2s but sometimes there are some delay-peaks with over 2s of delay.
I think it appears as soon as client b gets too many messages at the same time from the a clients.
Has anybody of you guys an idea what's the reason for this and how I can solve this?
Thanks and stay healthy!

When the run() is called, client a publishes to client b

client a

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


class CarClient:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(id)
        self.client.connect("192.168.178.41", 1883, 60)  # connect to broker
        self.newSpeed = 0
        self.holdSpeedTime = 5
        self.speedDuration = 0
        self.id = id
        self.time_sent = 0

    def on_connect(self, mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
        print("connected" + str(rc))

    def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
        answerTuple = eval(msg.payload)
        self.newSpeed = int(answerTuple[0])
        self.holdSpeedTime = answerTuple[1]
        self.client.unsubscribe("test_channel")
        time_feedback = time.time()
        delay = time_feedback - self.time_sent
        print(str(delay))

    def on_disconnect(self, mqttc, flags, rc):
        print("disconnected" + str(rc))

    def on_publish(self, mqttc, obj, mid):
        print("Data published " + str(mid))
        print("published")

    def on_subscribe(self, mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

    def on_unsubscribe(self, mqttc, flags, rc):
        print("unsubscribed" + str(rc))

    def on_log(self, mqttc, obj, level, string):
        print(string)

    def run(self, carID, connectionPoint):
        self.time_sent = time.time()
        self.tuple = (carID, connectionPoint)

        # assining functions to callback
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        # self.client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        # self.client.on_unsubscribe = self.on_unsubscribe
        self.client.loop_start()
        self.client.subscribe(str(self.id), 0)  # subscribe topic

        self.client.publish("test_channel1", str(self.tuple))

        time.sleep(1)

        carFeedback = (self.newSpeed, self.holdSpeedTime)
        self.newSpeed = 0
        self.holdSpeedTime = 5

        return carFeedback
```

client b

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

crossingList = []



def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):  # create function for callback
    print("subscribed with qos", granted_qos, "\n")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc=0):
    print("disconnected")


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("connected")


def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    dataTuple = eval(message.payload)  # message is a tuple of (carID, connectionPoint)
    print(str(dataTuple))
    addToList(dataTuple)


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("published")


def addToList(dataTuple):
    carID = dataTuple[0]
    connectionPoint = dataTuple[1]
    crossingList.append((carID, connectionPoint))


def logic():
    carID = crossingList.__getitem__(0)[0]
    connectionPoint = crossingList.__getitem__(0)[1]

    if connectionPoint == 600:

        newSpeed = 400
        holdTime = 5
        client.publish( carID, str((newSpeed, holdTime)))
        del crossingList[0]

    else:
        newSpeed = 500
        holdTime = 3
        client.publish(carID, str((newSpeed, holdTime)))
        del crossingList[0]



client = mqtt.Client("Logic")  # create client object

client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe  # assign function to callback
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect  # assign function to callback
client.on_connect = on_connect  # assign function to callback
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("192.168.178.41", 1883, 60)  # establish connection
time.sleep(0.1)
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe("test_channel1")
count = 1
while True:  # runs forever break with CTRL+C
    if len(crossingList) != 0:
        logic()
    else:
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: What are the maximum number of transactions that can be expected at a given point of time?

Comment: client a publishes a message to client b and client b as soon as he got the message a message back to client a. So the max amount would be 7*2 if all clients a are publishing at the same time

Comment: I may further look into your program to see what exactly is causing this issue. Please edit  the question and add the program you have tried

Comment: so you think its because a wrong piece of code and that its not normal for mqtt to take that long time, even if there are seven clients publishing to one topic and at the same time?

Comment: i edited my question and added the code of client b. If there is a mistake it should be there

Comment: I am not sure if it is because of the wrong piece of code. I am just trying to see all the possibilities. I will take a look into your program now. However, I have a small suggestion. Why can't you use different Topics for different publishers? It is always a good idea to use it this way.

Comment: This is a distributed system. You need to look at the whole system, not just one of the clients. The delay could be down to any (or something totally different) of the following 1) The network, 2) The broker, 3) What else is running on the pi's. Also how are you measuring time? Are you sure the clocks on all the devices are synchronised to the same network time source?

Comment: edited accordingly.. there you can see how I measured the time. I will try different topics @Solen'ya

Comment: MQTT in a LAN (assumed, because you are connecting to a broker on 192.168.178.41) should handle 1000's of clients with off-the-shelf software. Putting a network sniffer like wireshark will show you where the delays are in 5 minutes on such a small scenario. We routinely handle scenarios with hundreds of thousands of clients, then it takes a little longer.